# How to get multiple .js files working (Only the first .js file is working)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Have an HTML as with 2 .js files called as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel=stylesheet href=style.css>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="js/ex1.js"> </script>
<script src="js/ex2.js"> </script>

</html>
```

But only the first .js file works (in the above code, ex1.js is working)

If I put the files as below "ex2.js" is working !!!. Can you let me know what I am doing wrong? I want to get both of them working together.

````
</body>
<script src="js/ex2.js"> </script>
<script src="js/ex1.js"> </script>

</html>
```
````

Comment: Without knowing what the code does how can we help? You need to produce a [mcve] to narrow the question down with relevant code.

Comment: Check from browser network tab if the second js file is loading

Comment: I think the problem is inside your is files. What is the content of js files? Have you some function with the same name in your files?

Comment: @Andy I could not put the code because there is option to put JS code in one place but I have 2 js scripts.

Comment: @Stefino76 YES. Both JS scripts have the same function names. Even though the names are same the variables inside are different & I thought it would work (I am new to JS).I will change the names & see if they work.

Comment: @Stefino76 You were right. The issue was with the variable & function names in the JS script. I changed them & both scripts are working together now. If you can put this as your answer, I will accept & Up-Vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if you have some function in your js files with the same name. If so, only one function will works.